# Create a column of date in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extend series of dates in Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25344/how-to-extend-series-of-dates-in-google-docs)

In Excel, when you enter a date and hold <kbd>right click button</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> and move the mouse, it will create dates.

Is there a way to create a column of date easily with Google Spreadsheets like with Excel?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In both Excel and Google Spreadsheet...

1. Enter a date in a cell
2. With LEFT mouse button, click (and hold) square handle in bottom right corner of cell.
3. Drag the selection to cover all cells you wish to be dates.
4. Release mouse button.

However, Google Spreadsheet will fill the selection with the same date, unlike Excel that fills a sequence of consecutive dates.

To make a sequence of dates in Google Spreadsheet, complete the first **two** cells manually and select these **two** cells to drag over the required range of cells. Google Spreadsheet then continues the sequence.

**UPDATE 3-Jun-2020:** Not sure when this behaviour changed, but you now only need to select a single date before dragging to create a sequence of dates increasing by 1 day. In this respect, the behaviour is now the same as Excel.

Note that you do need to make sure you have selected the appropriate locale and date format for this to work as intended. See the [following WebApps answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89846/5434) for more detail on this.

---

> In Excel, enter a date, hold right click button + shift and move the mouse to create dates

This does not work for me in Excel?

Comment: When I do this in spreadsheet, I have the same date in all cell

Comment: Ah, you wish to create a sequence of dates... 2012-09-04, 2012-09-05, etc... Then you need to manually create the first **two** entries and select these two entries before dragging the selection.

Comment: This only works if the locale (File->Settings) of the document is correct AND all your dates are in the correct format. Google assumes American date formats, rather than the format used by the rest of the planet.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, even after using the correct locale and making sure the format is right. Only the YEAR of the dates in question is changed, not the day and month, which obviously should change first.

Comment: @grunwald2.0 The same method still works OK for me in the latest Google Sheets. You can use the same method to create different sequences of dates (every other day, every 7 days, etc.) There would seem to be _something else_ that is preventing this from working in your case.

Comment: @w3d: My problem still persists as of 13th of December 2015...

Comment: @grunwald2.0 What dates are you selecting before trying to create a sequence?

Comment: NOt working as of now.

Comment: @ledawg Still works for me. In fact, it's "easier" than it used to be as you no longer need to select a sequence of two dates. Simply selecting a single date and dragging this down (using the drag-control in the bottom right corner of the cell) to cover all required cells creates a sequence of consecutive (+1 day) dates. In this respect it works the same as Excel. Is the sheet set to the required "locale" and date format?

Comment: @mrwhite I just tried this procedure on two dates in two adjacent fields. It just repeats the two i stead of incrementing.

Comment: @ledawg For me, it only "repeats the two dates" if I also hold the **Ctrl** key down whilst dragging. Have you confirmed the "locale" setting for the current sheet and date format in the cells? The locale/date format appears to be the issue that has prevented this from working for other users in the past (as stated in the [linked question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25344/how-to-extend-series-of-dates-in-google-docs)).

Comment: @mrwhite it doesn't change the behaviour.  I use the Anglo-Saxon date formatting so this should work. Changing it to me geographic locale did not help.

Comment: This only changes the YEAR, not MONTH or DAY!

Comment: @loretoparisi There must be something different in your config/formatting/locale or _something_ that results in that behaviour? Whatever format/setting I use, it always increases by +1 day.

Comment: @MrWhite confirmed, it must be set the right locale, that is not automatic: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89846/122486